# BOOT_COMPLETED intent not received on Samsung J7 Max

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Samsung Galaxy J7 Max for which I am writing a simple application that returns to the home screen when used. This app is suppose to startup when the device first powers on and also if the device reboots.

None of the above is happening even though when I have tested the app on a virtual device and have the appropriate permissions and the appropriate broadcast receiver in place.

I have also added several tweaks from reading answers and suggestions from SO regarding this same problem. But none of them have worked. I don't think Samsung 
its apps.

Here is the code in the AndroidManifest.xml that I am using-:

```
<receiver
            android:name="foobar.alex.foobar.BootCompleted"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.REBOOT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Also note my phone is secured by a password and fingerprint, would this cause any problems ?